# Dynamic series in stacked column chart is not showing sometimes

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, charts, flex4, adobe

I have a stacked column chart in which varying data may come. The issue is happening if autoAdjust in vertical axis is set to true, then some series are not showing(because axis value is not reaching upto the range of series value). if we are setting autoaxis to false and manually maximum and minimum values, then all the series are showing properly but manual axis setup is possible only when we know about data already. My data is dynamic and there is no idea about maximum axis value . Is there any workaround for the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a function that cycles through all the series' data inside of your chart using the "render" event. This event is dispatched just before anything is rendered and can be used to calculate the maximum value that your chart can render.

If you want to take advantage of the "min" calculation made in the following example set your vertical axis "baseAtZero" property to "false".

Here is the example:

```
<mx:Canvas 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    creationComplete="init()"
    click="generateRandomData()"
    >

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.charts.chartClasses.AxisBase;
            import mx.charts.chartClasses.ChartBase;
            import mx.charts.chartClasses.Series;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable]
            public var testData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            public function init():void{
                generateRandomData();
            }

            public function generateRandomData():void{
                var randomNumberOfObject:int = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100));
                var i:int = 0;
                var resultData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

                if(randomNumberOfObject <= 1){
                    randomNumberOfObject = 2;
                }

                while(i < randomNumberOfObject){
                    var dataObject:Object = new Object();
                    dataObject.date = i;
                    dataObject.value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
                    dataObject.value2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
                    dataObject.value3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));

                    resultData.addItem(dataObject);
                    i++;
                }

                testData = resultData;
            }

            public function adjustVerticalLabels(e:Event = null):void{
                var chartSeries:Array = (e.currentTarget as ChartBase).series;
                var vAxis:* = null;
                var size:int = chartSeries.length;
                var max:Number = 0;
                var min:Number = NaN;

                for each(var series:* in chartSeries){
                    if(vAxis == null){
                        vAxis = (series as Series).getAxis(ChartBase.VERTICAL);
                    }
                    if(series.enabled == true){
                        var dataField:String = series.yField;
                        for each(var item:* in series.dataProvider){
                            if(item[dataField] > max){
                                max = item[dataField];
                            }
                            if(isNaN(min)){
                                min = item[dataField];
                            }else{
                                if(item[dataField] < min){
                                    min = item[dataField];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                vAxis.minimum = min;
                if(max > 2){
                    vAxis.maximum = max;
                }else{
                    //Used when the chart values are very small
                    vAxis.maximum = 2;
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:BarChart id="lineChart"
        width="100%" height="100%"
        showDataTips="true"
        dataTipMode="single"
        seriesFilters="{[]}"
        dataProvider="{testData}"
        render="adjustVerticalLabels(event)"
        >
        <mx:horizontalAxis>
            <mx:CategoryAxis  id="testXAxis" 
                dataProvider="{testData}" 
                categoryField="date"
                />
        </mx:horizontalAxis>

        <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:LinearAxis id="textYAxis"
                baseAtZero="false"
                />
        </mx:verticalAxis>

        <mx:series>
            <mx:ColumnSeries 
                yField="value" 
                displayName="Value"
                />
            <mx:ColumnSeries 
                yField="value2" 
                displayName="Value2"
                />
            <mx:ColumnSeries 
                yField="value2" 
                displayName="Value3"
                />
        </mx:series>
    </mx:BarChart>

</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Actually my problem is different but the render event that you have coded here helped me to identify the problem in my chart. :-) Keep Contributing.

Comment: It is good if some one get help from this [LINK](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2009/04/14/missing-values-in-flex-charts.html)